# PDFs suddenly loose quality after cropping in Adobe Illustrator and get pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, image-quality, crop, pixelation

I routinely placed and cropped PDFs within Illustrator, without any issue. From today, when I crop a placed PDF, it gets kind of pixelated after cropping (example below). This never happened before. The quality loss is also observable after exporting the project.

I already removed and re-installed Illustrator, but this didn't help.

Can you please advice how I can fix this?

*Edit: This is how I crop an image: First I select the PDF object with the selection tool. Then I click on "Crop Image" on the Properties panel under "Quick Access". Then I select the area how to crop the image. To finish the process I click "Apply" on the Properties panel under "Quick Actions".

[image]

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with point? Could you further elaborate how to solve the access issue?

Comment: Ah yes crop is meant for cropping raster objects. Kts not meant for wht you are using it.

Comment: Maybe don't use cropping for this because it will rasterize the image. This is normal behaviour and there is nothing wrong.  Instead use a clipping mask.

Comment: Thank you joojaa and Billy Kerr! As you said the solution is to use a clipping mask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Links panel and make sure the linked PDF is where it is supposed to be.

If you see this icon, the PDF link must be fixed. With a broken link, AI renders a low-res, pixelated preview of previously-linked files.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason was actually that I need to use a clopping mask instead of the cropping tool. The cropping tool caused rasterization of my pdf.